# How can get the values of NSDictionary using keys where the dictionaries are stored in NSArray?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have created 5 NSDictionary's. I stored them in NSArray. I need to get the values stored in NSDictionaries. How can do it ?
I tried calling `[[array objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:key1]`.
But, it is crashing by giving the message:unrecognized selector sent to instance 
How to get the data ?

```
NSDictionary *enemy1, *enemy2;
NSArray *enemyData;
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
enemy1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"3", @"Countdown speed", @"3", @"Enemy gun draw", @"1", @"Enemy gun fire", @"0.8", @"Enemy hit probability", @"1", @"Enemy re-fire interval", nil];
enemy2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"3", @"Countdown speed", @"2.8", @"Enemy gun draw", @"0.9", @"Enemy gun fire", @"0.8", @"Enemy hit probability", @"0.9", @"Enemy re-fire interval", nil];    
enemyData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"enemy1", @"enemy2", nil];
NSLog(@"Value in Array: %f", [ [enemyData objectAtIndex:1]objectForKey:@"Enemy gun draw"] );
}
```

Comment: That's the correct method; so if it's not working something else is wrong (for example, maybe the object you're retrieving isn't really an NSDictionary). It might help to post the code you're using to create, store, and access the NSDictionary's, plus the exact error message.

Comment: It might also help to break the call out into intermediate steps (e.g. get the dictionary out of the array into a temporary variable. If that doesn't immediately lead you to the problem you might find it easier to step through in the debugger at that point.

Comment: I posted my program also. Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding the strings @"enemy1" and @"enemy2" to your array, not the dictionaries.

Correct the line as follows: `nemyData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:enemy1, enemy2, nil];` and you should be good.

Note that you might run into a memory problem because your variables are autoreleased, if you want to access them later (which i suppose) you need to retain them.

Comment: thank you for the help and suggestion on memory problem. I corrected my code.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the issue you raised (which has already been answered), there is also a problem with the NSLog format string.  %f is for doubles, not objects.  You need to use %@ to format anything returned by NSDictionary's objectForKey: method.  Incidentally, the objects you are storing are NSStrings.  NSNumbers might be better e.g.

```
enemy1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: 3], @"Countdown speed",
                          [NSNumber numberWithDouble: 1.0], @"Enemy gun fire"...
```